# Issue with Multi-Column Bullet List and Default CSS Settings, HTML5

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, bulletedlist

I'm a frequent visitor to this site and love it! To give background of knowledge level, I took a beginning web programming course in Fall 2012.

**Objective**: Write code in Javascript (for reuse) to create a multi-column bullet list that prints as follows:

Attributes (this is a heading)

- Attr1   * Attr2
- Attr3   * Attr4
- Attr5   * Attr6

Note: Phillipe's solution works. Given at bottom. Objective achieved.

After searching for how to achieve this objective, I tried the following code

**Code Written**

**Code in Question**: http://jsfiddle.net/M5M8R/

```
 <p>Attributes
   <ul>
     <li style="float: left;">
       <ul>
         <li>Attr1</li>
         <li>Attr3</li>
         <li>Attr5</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li style="float: left;">
       <ul>
         <li>Attr2</li>
         <li>Attr4</li>
         <li>Attr6</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </p>
```

**Full Code (If you want to see it--Don't worry it's not too long!)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>
      Bullet Column Test
    </title>    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <style type="text/css">
    h1 {text-align:center}
    h2 {margin-bottom:0;}
    p  {margin-top:0;}
    body {color: #039; background-color: #eeff77;}
    ul{padding: 0; list-style: square;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* <![CDATA[ */

      function printBulletList(heading, headingLevel, bulletArray, noOfColsRequested) {

      //Divide number of bullets in bullet array by no of requested columns to determine
      //How many rows will be needed
        var noOfRows = Math.ceil(bulletArray.length/noOfColsRequested);

      //If no of cols requested exceeds no of bullets then set no of cols to no of bullets  
        var noOfCols;
        if (bulletArray.length < noOfColsRequested)
          noOfCols = bulletArray.length;
        else
          noOfCols = noOfColsRequested;

       //Write html for heading, followed by unordered list column by column
        document.write("<p>");
        document.write("<h"+headingLevel+">"+heading+"</h"+headingLevel+">");
        document.write("<ul>");
          for (i=0; i<noOfCols; i++) {
            document.write("<li style='float:left;'>");
              document.write("<ul>");
                for (j=0; j< noOfRows; j++) {
                  //since last row may not be fully populated, do not write if reached end of bullet array
                  if ((i + noOfCols*j) < bulletArray.length)
                    document.write("<li>"+bulletArray[i+noOfCols*j]+"</li>");
                }    
              document.write("</ul>");
            document.write("</li>");
          }
        document.write("</ul>");
        document.write("</p>");
        document.write("<br>");
      }
      /* ]]> */
    </script>        
</head>

<body> 
 <div> 
 <p>Attributes
   <ul>
     <li style="float: left;">
       <ul>
         <li>Attr1</li>
         <li>Attr3</li>
         <li>Attr5</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li style="float: left;">
       <ul>
         <li>Attr2</li>
         <li>Attr4</li>
         <li>Attr6</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </p>
 <br>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
 testArray = new Array("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7");
 printBulletList("Tests", 2, testArray, 4); 
 /* ]]> */
 </script>
 <br>
 <br>  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Issue**

(1) I used LTS (less than slash) to write the code. It works fine when I preview it in LTS but
all bullets become collapsed when I open the file in a browser. So the first row appears as:

Attr*1Attr2 (the bullet for Attr1 disappears and the bullet for Attr2 is superimposed atop end of Attr1). See jsfiddle link above.

I expect it is a matter of default CSS settings for a browser. Inline CSS prevails over browser settings so I expect it is a question of what is default for LTS versus what is default for browser for a setting I don't specify. Which one?

(2) Whatever follows the bullet columns in body will print to the right of the bullet columns (e.g. heading of second set of bullets prints to the right of first set of bullets unless I manually enter additional [br] in the body. Is there a smarter way?

Thanks for any help!

---

**Solution**

Philippe's solution works! Here is the modified script if anyone else wants to use it.

```
  function printBulletList(heading, headingLevel, bulletArray, noOfColsRequested) {

  //Divide number of bullets in bullet array by no of requested columns to determine
  //How many rows will be needed
    var noOfRows = Math.ceil(bulletArray.length/noOfColsRequested);

  //If no of cols requested exceeds no of bullets then set no of cols to no of bullets  
    var noOfCols;
    if (bulletArray.length < noOfColsRequested)
      noOfCols = bulletArray.length;
    else
      noOfCols = noOfColsRequested;

   //Write html for heading, followed by unordered list column by column
    document.write("<div class='wrapper'>");
    document.write("<p>");

    //Heading level 0 is used when there is no heading, and no space desired between successive
    //columns of bullets
    if (headingLevel > 0) {
      document.write("<h"+headingLevel+">"+heading+"</h"+headingLevel+">");
      document.write("<br>");
    }
    for (i=0; i<noOfCols; i++) {
      if (headingLevel > 0)
        document.write("<ul style='float: left; top-margin: 1em; bottom-margin: 1em;'>");
      else
        document.write("<ul style='float: left; top-margin: 0; bottom-margin: 0;'>");
            for (j=0; j< noOfRows; j++) {
              //since last row may not be fully populated, do not write if reached end of bullet array
            if ((i + noOfCols*j) < bulletArray.length)
              document.write("<li>"+bulletArray[i+noOfCols*j]+"</li>");
            }
      document.write("</ul>");
    }
    document.write("</p>");
    if (headingLevel > 0)
      document.write("<br>");
    document.write("</div>");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I not understand the question, but why you use many ul li ul li ?
http://jsfiddle.net/C9A4j/

```
<ul style="float: left;">
    <li>Attr1</li>
    <li>Attr3</li>
    <li>Attr5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You understood it perfectly. I did not know how to create multi-column lists and got the code I used by searching on the web. Oddly enough it worked in LTS. Your solution works--thanks! I am adding the modified script to my question above in case anyone else wants to use it.

Comment: I did try to vote it up but the site will not let me until I have 15 reputation points. So I have given credit with my words and I hope someone else will fill in for me and vote it up via the site system.